# CRUD/Restful API - > GET/DELETE doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, crud

I've got a problem with my API, I've made a new Entity, DAO, service and controller. POST(addEmployer) and GET(findEveryEmployer) works without a problem. But the ones for finding by ID and deleting by ID doesn't work and I can't find an error. I'm using postman for testing my restful service, "api/praktykodawcy/1" either GET or DELETE shows NOT_FOUND (and yes there are at least 2 employeers with correct ids in database)

Here is the code of controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/praktykodawcy")
public class PraktykodawcyController {

    private iPraktykodawcyService ipraktykodawcyService;

    @Autowired
    PraktykodawcyController(iPraktykodawcyService ipraktykodawcyService) {
        this.ipraktykodawcyService = ipraktykodawcyService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity> addEmployeer (@RequestBody PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity) throws Exception {
        try {
            PraktykodawcyEntity newEmployeer = ipraktykodawcyService.addEmployeer(praktykodawcyEntity);
            return new ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity>(newEmployeer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<PraktykodawcyEntity>> findEveryEmployeer () {
        List<PraktykodawcyEntity> list = ipraktykodawcyService.findEveryEmployeer();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<PraktykodawcyEntity>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{idPraktykodawcy}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity> findByIdPraktykodawcy(@PathVariable int idPraktykodawcy) {
        PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity = ipraktykodawcyService.findEmployeer(idPraktykodawcy);
        if(praktykodawcyEntity !=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity>(praktykodawcyEntity, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{idPraktykodawcy}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity> deleteEmployeer(@PathVariable int idPraktykodawcy) {
        PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity = ipraktykodawcyService.deleteEmployeer(idPraktykodawcy);
        if(praktykodawcyEntity !=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity>(praktykodawcyEntity, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PraktykodawcyService implements iPraktykodawcyService {

    @Autowired
    private iPraktykodawcyDAO ipraktykodawcyDAO;

    @Override
    public PraktykodawcyEntity addEmployeer(PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity) {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.addEmployeer(praktykodawcyEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public PraktykodawcyEntity updateEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy, PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity) {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.updateEmployeer(idPraktykodawcy, praktykodawcyEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public PraktykodawcyEntity deleteEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy) {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.deleteEmployeer(idPraktykodawcy);
    }

    @Override
    public PraktykodawcyEntity findEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy) {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.findEmployeer(idPraktykodawcy);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PraktykodawcyEntity> findEveryEmployeer() {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.findEveryEmployeer();
    }

    @Override
    public List<PraktykodawcyEntity> findByIdAdresu(int idAdresu) {
        return ipraktykodawcyDAO.findByIdAdresu(idAdresu);
    }
}
```

and DAO

```
@Repository
public class PraktykodawcyDAO implements iPraktykodawcyDAO {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public PraktykodawcyEntity addEmployeer(PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity) {
    em.persist(praktykodawcyEntity);
    return praktykodawcyEntity;
}

@Override
public PraktykodawcyEntity updateEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy, PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity) {
    em.merge(praktykodawcyEntity);
    return praktykodawcyEntity;
}

@Override
public PraktykodawcyEntity deleteEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy) {
    PraktykodawcyEntity praktykodawcyEntity = em.find(PraktykodawcyEntity.class, idPraktykodawcy);
    if(praktykodawcyEntity !=null) {
        em.remove(praktykodawcyEntity);
        return praktykodawcyEntity;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public PraktykodawcyEntity findEmployeer(int idPraktykodawcy) {
    return em.find(PraktykodawcyEntity.class, idPraktykodawcy);

}

@Override
public List<PraktykodawcyEntity> findEveryEmployeer() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM PraktykodawcyEntity e");
    return query.getResultList();
}

@Override
public List<PraktykodawcyEntity> findByIdAdresu(int idAdresu) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM PraktykodawcyEntity e WHERE e.adresyByIdAdresu.idAdresu=?1");
    query.setParameter(1, idAdresu);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

}

Comment: Attaching a debugger would be more fruitful at this point.  404 on a restful resource that you're *certain* you've created means that it's either not persisting correctly or you're not retrieving it correctly.

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: Is your controller code executed? If so, what is the value of id field? And does an entity with this id actually exist in the database?

Comment: Too be honest I've never debugged my restful service, was using only postman plugin for chrome. I've checked my POST method and it works, GET(findEveryEmployer) shows 2 employers with id = 1 and id = 2, I've even checked my db with pgadmin (SELECT * FROM praktykodawcy WHERE id_praktykodawcy=1) and it shows correct employer. example of postman: `{
        "idPraktykodawcy": 1,
        "nazwa": "Microsoft",
        "nazwaDzialalnosci": "software engineering",
        "zaufany": true,
        "idAdresu": null,
        "adresyByIdAdresu": null
    },`

Comment: Yes but debugging will confirm if id 1 is being passed successfully to your DAO. It is all well saying the record is in the database but you haven't verified what you code is doing when you pass it this id. If you are not familiar with using a debugger, add some console output statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the variable name to the `@PathVariable` annotations. 
Try this:

```
public ResponseEntity<PraktykodawcyEntity> 
    findByIdPraktykodawcy(@PathVariable("idPraktykodawcy") int idPraktykodawcy)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've made 2 other entities with birelation without annotation like yours and they works. I can show You how they look like, I've been starring at this code for 2 hours, still nothing, I think they look almost the same except other names of DAOs, entities, etc

Comment: time to get out the debugger then :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay Guys, i have found what's wrong, first thing i made couples of prinln in code to check if id is being passed correctly through all modules, everything was right. But then i checked the Entity and saw that @OneToMany wasn't commented and it was searching through this relation with another Entity but that entity got its @ManyToOne commented and hibernated wasn't shouting at something like this. Now everthing works, going to get this birealtion working now, thanks Guys for quick answers.